# How to change the default tile when sending from Outlook to OneNote?

Tags: windows, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, microsoft-onenote

I use the "Send to OneNote" feature in Outlook quite a lot and I would like to customize the format of the note title when it is created in OneNote.

Currently I have the following title being used when creating notes from meetings:

```
<title of the meeting> - <date>
```

This is not very useful for recurrent meetings as what I see in the list of the notes in OneNote is

```
<title of the mee 
<title of the mee 
<title of the mee
```

When this is actually

```
<title of the meeting> - 12/10/2013
<title of the meeting> - 14/10/2013
<title of the meeting> - 16/10/2013
```

It would be way more useful to have the date first.

Is there a way to configure the format of the titles of notes created from Outlook?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not. I recommend raising this in one of the Microsoft Office forums.

OneNote is extremely useful but not very configurable.